# cmake could not find SDK10

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I have a problem with cmake after I installed a new SDK 10 version (now it should be 10.0.10586.0). But when I run cmake cmakelists.txt, I got this error message:

-- Building for: Visual Studio 14 2015
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.

I googled a while but could not find the right answer. My problem is that I can use VS2015 to build my application (old projects) using the new SDK. Everything seems to be fine. But cmake will try to build one small generated project (CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj). But in this project, SDK 8 is used (which is not available in my system anymore).

Could you help me, many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved (sorta of), I have to reinstall an older version of SDK10 aside from the version 10.0.10586.0. It is weird that uninstalling the older version had somehow damaged the environment.